# Removing Redundancy

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was told I should post this code here because I have a good amount of redundancy in the code. I am new to JS and would appreciate any help in condensing this code and having it still function the same. Does anyone see anything I can do better to help make this code run more smoothly?

https://jsfiddle.net/bobrierton/1m5thp43/

```
/* eslint-env node, browser */
/* eslint spaced-comment: 0, quotes: 0, brace-style: 0, indent: 0, max-len: 0, no-alert: 0 */
import precise from './precise';

// refactored from CreditCalc()
function calculateCredit(options) {
  let cmnv = Number(options.tCreditMonths); // get credit months
  const ctwv = Number(options.tCreditWeight); // get credit weight or length
  const cccv = Number(options.creditClass); // get credit _class
  let cctot = 0; //base tax breakdown  // GR (General Revenue)

  if (!cmnv || !ctwv || !cccv) {
    return precise(0);
  }

  if (cccv !== 0) {
    if ((cccv === 1) && (ctwv < 2500)) //base tax _class 01(01)
    {
        cctot = 14.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //14.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 1) && (ctwv > 2499) && (ctwv < 3500)) //base tax _class 01(02)
    {
        cctot = 22.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //22.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 1) && (ctwv > 3499) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //base tax _class 01(03)
    {
        cctot = 32.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //32.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 9) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //_class 9 lease
    {
        if (cmnv > 6) {
            cmnv = 6;
        } //_class 9 credit max credit 1/2 of annual tax amount
        cctot = ((17.00 + (1.50 * (Math.round(ctwv / 100))))) * (cmnv / 12);
    } //17.00 Flat of which 4.50 is GR and 1.50 per cwt of which .50 is GR
    if ((cccv === 14) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) // non-resident military
    {
        cctot = 4.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } // 4.00 Flat - 1 of which is GR

    if ((cccv === 31) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 1999)) // truck _class 31(31)
    {
        cctot = 14.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //14.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 31) && (ctwv > 1999) && (ctwv <= 3000)) //truck _class 31(32)
    {
        cctot = 22.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //22.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 31) && (ctwv > 3000) && (ctwv <= 5000)) //truck _class 31(33)
    {
        cctot = 32.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //32.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 36) && (ctwv > 1951) && (ctwv <= 50049)) //_class 36 bus
    {
        cctot = ((17.00 + (2.00 * (Math.round(ctwv / 100))))) * (cmnv / 12);
    } //////////////////////////////??????
    if ((cccv === 37) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 80000)) //base tax fees 0.00 - no credit
    {
        cctot = 0.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //no credit
    if ((cccv === 39) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //Forestry use trucks
    {
        cctot = 324.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //324.00 Flat-84.00 of which is GR (General Revenue)
    if ((cccv === 42) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 4499)) //_class 42 motorcoach, chassis mount truck camper, motor home
    {
        cctot = 27.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //27.00 Flat - 7 which is GR
    if ((cccv === 42) && (ctwv > 4499) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //_class 42, Motor coach, motor home, chassis mount truck camper,
    {
        cctot = 47.25 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //47.25 Flat - 12.25 which is GR //_class 42 ends
    if ((cccv === 50) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //non-res military MH (HS)
    {
        cctot = 4.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //4.00 Flat - 1.00 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 35)) //base tax - begin 51 HS
    {
        cctot = 20.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //20.00 flat
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 35) && (ctwv <= 40)) {
        cctot = 25.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //25.00 flat
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 40) && (ctwv <= 45)) {
        cctot = 30.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //30.00 flat
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 45) && (ctwv <= 50)) {
        cctot = 35.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //35.00 flat
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 50) && (ctwv <= 55)) {
        cctot = 40.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //40.00 flat
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 55) && (ctwv <= 60)) {
        cctot = 45.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //45.00 flat
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 60) && (ctwv <= 65)) {
        cctot = 50.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //50.00 flat
    if ((cccv === 51) && (ctwv > 65) && (ctwv <= 99)) {
        cctot = 80.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //80.00 flat  // end 51 HS
    if ((cccv === 52) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 500)) //_class 52 trailer < 500 lbs
    {
        cctot = 6.75 * (cmnv / 12);
    } // 6.75 Flat - 1.75 which is GR
    if ((cccv === 53) && (ctwv > 500) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //base tax _class 53
    {
        cctot = ((3.50 + (1.00 * (Math.round(ctwv / 100))))) * (cmnv / 12);
    } //53credit per100lbs //3.50 Flat - which 1 is GR and 1.00 per cwt of which .25 is GR
    if ((cccv === 54) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 1999)) // _class 54
    {
        if (cmnv > 6) {
            cmnv = 6;
        }
        cctot = ((3.50 + (1.50 * (Math.round(ctwv / 100))))) * (cmnv / 12);
    } //3.50 Flat - which 1 is GR and 1.50 per cwt of which .50 is GR
    if ((cccv === 54) && (ctwv > 1999) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //_class 54
    {
        if (cmnv > 6) {
            cmnv = 6;
        }
        cctot = ((13.50 + (1.50 * (Math.round(ctwv / 100))))) * (cmnv / 12);
    } //13.50 Flat - which 3.50 is GR and 1.50 per cwt of which .50 is GR  //_class 54 end
    if ((cccv === 56) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //_class 56 semi-trailer - flat fee
    {
        cctot = 13.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //13.50 Flat-3.50 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 62) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //62 camp trailer
    {
        cctot = 13.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //13.50 Flat - 3.50 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 65) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //65 MC
    {
        cctot = 10.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //10.00 Flat
    if ((cccv === 69) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //69 moped /motorized bike
    {
        cctot = 5.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //5.00 Flat
    if ((cccv === 70) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //70 transporter
    {
        cctot = 101.25 * (cmnv / 12);
    } // 101.25 flat - 26.25 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 71) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //dealer plates
    {
        cctot = 17.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } // 17.00 flat - 4.50 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 74) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //boat trailer dealer plates
    {
        cctot = 17.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } // 17.00 flat - 4.50 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 76) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //76 Park Trailer
    {
        cctot = 25.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //25.00 Flat
    if ((cccv === 77) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 35)) //77 travel trailer thru 35
    {
        cctot = 27.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //27.00 Flat- 7 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 78) && (ctwv > 35) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //78 travel trailer over 35
    {
        cctot = 25.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //25.00 Flat
    if ((cccv === 80) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //antique motorcycle
    {
        cctot = 7.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //7.50 Flat-2.50 of which is GF
    if ((cccv === 82) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //_class 82 Horseless Carriage
    {
        cctot = 7.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //7.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 91) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //_class 91/95 Antique truck/military trailer
    {
        cctot = 7.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //7.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 92) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //ambulance,hearse,non-41 wrecker
    {
        cctot = 40.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //40.50 flat- of which 10.50 is GR
    if ((cccv === 93) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //goat 93
    {
        cctot = 7.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //7.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 94) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //tractor crane (tools)
    {
        cctot = 44.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //44.00 Flat-11.50 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 95) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //antique car
    {
        cctot = 7.50 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //7.50 Flat
    if ((cccv === 96) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //x-series exempt
    {
        cctot = 4.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } // 4.00 Flat - 1.00 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 97) && (ctwv >= 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //permanent,all govt - no credit
    {
        cctot = 0.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    }
    if ((cccv === 100) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //vessels - no credit
    {
        cctot = 0.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    }
    if ((cccv === 101) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //vessel dealer - no credit
    {
        cctot = 0.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    }
    if ((cccv === 102) && (ctwv > 5000) && (ctwv <= 43999)) //Agricultural use trucks
    {
        cctot = 87.75 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //87.75 Flat-22.75 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 102) && (ctwv > 43999) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //Agricultural use trucks
    {
        cctot = 324.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //324.00 Flat-84.00 of which is GR
    if ((cccv === 103) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //_class 103 permanent (semi)TRL - no credit
    {
        cctot = 0.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    } //no credit
    if ((cccv === 104) && (ctwv > 0) && (ctwv <= 99999)) //vessel exempt - no credit
    {
        cctot = 0.00 * (cmnv / 12);
    }
    // add in a yes/no app alert - if _class 41 is also a wrecker:

    // _class 41 wrecker credit starts by weight category)
    if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 5000)) {
        const cResponseA41 = window.confirm('\nIs this class code 41 also a wrecker?\n\nOK = Yes\nCancel = No');

      if (cResponseA41) {
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 5000) && (ctwv <= 5999)) {
              cctot = 60.75 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //60.75 Flat-15.75 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 5999) && (ctwv <= 7999)) {
              cctot = 87.75 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //87.75 Flat-22.75 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 7999) && (ctwv <= 9999)) {
              cctot = 103.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //103.00 Flat-27.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 9999) && (ctwv <= 14999)) {
              cctot = 118.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //118.00 Flat-31.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 14999) && (ctwv <= 19999)) {
              cctot = 177.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //177.00 Flat-46.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 19999) && (ctwv <= 26000)) {
              cctot = 251.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //251.00 Flat-65.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 26000) && (ctwv <= 34999)) {
              cctot = 324.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //324.00 Flat-84.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 34999) && (ctwv <= 43999)) {
              cctot = 405.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //405.00 Flat-105.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 43999) && (ctwv <= 54999)) {
              cctot = 772.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //772.00 Flat-200.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 54999) && (ctwv <= 61999)) {
              cctot = 915.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //915.00 Flat-237.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 61999) && (ctwv <= 71999)) {
              cctot = 1080.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //1080.00 Flat-280.00 of which is GR
          if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 71999) && (ctwv <= 80000)) {
              cctot = 1322.00 * (cmnv / 12);
          } //1322.00 Flat-343.00 of which is GR
      } else if (!cResponseA41) {
        // else if class 41 is not a wrecker then continue with the following:
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 5000) && (ctwv <= 5999)) {
            cctot = 60.75 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //60.75 Flat-15.75 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 5999) && (ctwv <= 7999)) {
            cctot = 87.75 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //87.75 Flat-22.75 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 7999) && (ctwv <= 9999)) {
            cctot = 103.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //103.00 Flat-27.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 9999) && (ctwv <= 14999)) {
            cctot = 118.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //118.00 Flat-31.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 14999) && (ctwv <= 19999)) {
            cctot = 177.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //177.00 Flat-46.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 19999) && (ctwv <= 26000)) {
            cctot = 251.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //251.00 Flat-65.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 26000) && (ctwv <= 34999)) {
            cctot = 324.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //324.00 Flat-84.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 34999) && (ctwv <= 43999)) {
            cctot = 405.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //405.00 Flat-105.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 43999) && (ctwv <= 54999)) {
            cctot = 773.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //773.00 Flat-201.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 54999) && (ctwv <= 61999)) {
            cctot = 916.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //916.00 Flat-238.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 61999) && (ctwv <= 71999)) {
            cctot = 1080.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //1080.00 Flat-280.00 of which is GR
        if ((cccv === 41) && (ctwv > 71999) && (ctwv <= 80000)) {
            cctot = 1322.00 * (cmnv / 12);
        } //1322.00 Flat-343.00 of which is GR
      }
    } // class 41 credit ends

    if ((cccv === 0)) {
        cctot = 0 * (cmnv / 12);
    }

    if (cctot === 0) {
      alert('No credit amount allowed for this class code.');
      return Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER; // important to return 0 so we can check for these conditions for validation
    }

    if (cctot <= 3 && cctot > 0) {
      alert('Credit under $3.00 not allowed');
      return Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER; // important to return 0 so we can check for these conditions for validation
    } else {
      cctot *= -1;
    }
  }
  return precise(cctot);
}
module.exports = calculateCredit;
```

Comment: Please edit your question to state _what the code does_, not what you would like to improve about it (we will review __all aspects__ for improvements, including repetition).

Comment: Two words "table driven".

Comment: To check if a variable is between two numbers i usually put both checks in the same parenthesis, with the variable in the middle. So i would type `(1999 < ctwv && ctwv <= 3000)` instead of `(ctwv > 1999) && (ctwv <= 3000)`. No big deal, but kind of a readability thing to me :o)

Answer (score 2):

I was going to rewrite the code, but there's some odd stuff, so I'll just give you some notes to consider:

- There are redundant checks of `cccv` to `0` after it has already been checked with `!cccv`.
- There are many redundant comparisons of `cccv` to the same number that can be eliminated by having all sub-comparisons grouped under a single comparison.

  In general, the repeating pattern is a comparison of `cccv` followed by a check of `cctw` being in a range. Imagine a data structure that can perform a lookup of `cccv`, which gives a list of ranges, each of which have either a corresponding function or a number by which you can multiply `(cmnv/12)`.
- The `cmnv/12` appears to happen on *every* branch. Put it once toward the end!
- Your code that runs when `cccv` is `41` performs many more comparisons of `cccv === 41` even  though we already know it's `41`.
- The `if (cResponseA41)` is followed by an `else if (!cResponseA41)`, which is redundnant, since that's the only other possibility. A  simple `else` should be used.
- The many branches under `if (cResponseA41)` and its corresponding (now corrected) `else` are identical. If that's the case, what's the point of the `confirm` dialog? If not, then something needs to change, and it will likely involve using a separate function to get the single value that differs in order to reduce the redundancy in all the sub branches.